# Are $\zeta'(0)$ and $\beta'(0)$ algebraic numbers?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemann-zeta-function, l-functions, dirichlet-series

Let $\zeta$ be the Riemann zeta function and $\beta$ the Dirichlet beta function. We know that $\zeta (0)=-1/2$ and $\beta (0)=1/2$ are algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$. This led me to the following question:

Are $\zeta'(0)$ and $\beta'(0)$ algebraic numbers?

It is known that
$$\zeta'(0)=\log\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},$$
$$\beta'(0)=\log\frac{\Gamma (1/4)^2}{2\sqrt{2}\pi}$$
and that $\pi$ and $\Gamma (1/4)$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.

Searching the decimal expansions of these constants on OEIS didn't yield anything, so I'm writing this question.

Comment: Not sure why there was a downvote, seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: I presume because the answer is comfortably 'no one believes it but we have no idea how to prove it as of right now'.